Не получается задеплоить сайт на Vercel (Django+React)
Сделан сайт на DjangoRF+React, структура такая:
> cafe_project {

> api {
 > __pycache__
 > migrations
 __init__.py
 admin.py
 apps.py
 models.py
 serializers.py
 signals.py
 tests.py
 urls.py
 views.py }

> cafe_project {
 > __pycache__
 __init__.py
 asgi.py
 settings.py
 urls.py
 wsgi.py }

> frontend {
 > __pycache__
 > media
 > migrations
 > node_modules
 > public
 > src
 > static
 > templates/frontend
 .gitignore
 __init__.py
 admin.py
 apps.py
 babel.config.json
 models.py
 package-lock.json
 package.json
 tests.py
 urls.py
 views.py
 webpack.config.js }

> node_modules

Pipfile
Pipfile.lock
README.md
db.sqlite3
manage.py
package-lock.json
requirements.txt
vercel.json
} 

versel.json:
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "cafe-project",
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/api/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/$1"
    },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "frontend/public/$1"
    }
  ],
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "frontend",
      "use": "@vercel/static-build",
      "config": { "debug": true }
    },
    {
      "src": "cafe_project/wsgi.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "vercel.python" }
    }
  ],
  "env": {
    "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE": "cafe_project.settings"
  }
} 

cafe_project/cafe_project/settings.py:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.vercel.app']

cafe_project/cafe_project/wsgi.py:
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'cafe_project.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()

app = application

Появляется ошибка:
404: NOT_FOUND
Code: NOT_FOUND 

Кто знает, помогите, пожалуйста. Делаю все впервые и самостоятельно, уже всю голову сломала..
